# Sql Server Value Method Returning only one value not multiple

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to return multiple element values into rows and I am running into the below issue of it not returning all instances in rows, I have isolated the issue down to a singleton problem.  I have referenced the below links:

http://www.jasonstrate.com/2010/11/xquery-for-the-non-expert-value/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175894.aspx

I have tried these:

```
,c.value('(Tags/Tag/text())[1]' , 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS Tag
```

And

```
,c.value('(//Tags/Tag)[1]' , 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS Tag
```

I used this to test to see if it would return the first and second instance and it does, but I want it returned as seperate rows.  So two rows instead of 2 columns

```
,c.value('(Tags/Tag)[1]' , 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS Tag
,c.value('(Tags/Tag)[2]' , 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS Tag2
```

Here is a snapshot of the xml

```
  <nsp:Tags>
    <nsp:Tag>Books</nsp:Tag>
    <nsp:Tag>Reading</nsp:Tag>
  </nsp:Tags>
```

Edit I was able to get it with

```
C.value('.', 'nvarchar(20)')
```

but is there a way to achieve the same thing by leaving the path in the value select, or do I have keep it in the apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return multiple rows, you cannot just use `.value()` alone - you'll need to combine it with a call to  `.nodes()` that'll give you one row of XML for each node that matches your XPath expression:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('.....' as nsp)
DECLARE @Data XML = '<nsp:Tags>
                        <nsp:Tag>Books</nsp:Tag>
                        <nsp:Tag>Reading</nsp:Tag>
                     </nsp:Tags>'

SELECT
   XTags.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
   @Data.nodes('/Tags/Tag') XTbl(XTags)
```